# How to implement International shipping using magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I have two questions.
1)I am working on an e-commerce website using magento.This is a India based e-commerce website. But we are doing international transaction also.So I need to convert Indian currency to dollars, and I need to show the the dollar value for customers when they are doing payment.
How I can implement this using magento?

2)Dollar value is changing day by day So how I can get it automatically based today's dollar rate?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of using Magneto is that you can simply install a plugin to do so. If you're looking for a free plugin use this: [ET Currency Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html) It dynamically gets the conversion rates and handles all of that for you.

If a paid extension is okay with you please choose the [AutoCurrency](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/autocurrency.html) plugin. It detects the IP address of the user and changes the currency based on that.

Comment: I can't able to register in this website :-(

Comment: When I am downloading its asking for registration.When I am doing registration its showing that user name already exist.But I tried with lot of other user name